# Browser Mediarecorder - API when capture more than one sources sometimes video will broken

Tags: node.js, electron, web-mediarecorder

My clien app is base on `Electron` so basically it's make of web tech.
Because I want to open two `MediaRecorder`s one for capture desktop screen and another for camera.
I provide a very simple example as follow. When I only use single `MediaRecorder` everything is work fine.
Then when I start to use both, some computers will get broken video occasionally during stop recording process or after `reset` few times.
Especially when computer is runing busy or situation that memory only left few but not really insufficient memory.

- [Example in Github](https://github.com/andyyou/video-demo/blob/master/renderer.js)

I try to use two invisible browser window(In Electron) and save in file each second to fix this problem but it's not fix the problem completely (Though it's getting better).

Another problem is I try to use `fs.createWriteStream` and `fs.write` with `dataavailable` event in Electron
but `dataavailable` event is not trigger everytime if I use slice time in `recorder.start(1000)` method.
The `dataavailable` problem will occur sometimes.

Is any suggestion for this requirements